# using python cassandra driver in multithread to write to db

Tags: python, multithreading, cassandra

I'm writing a small Python script to async the data into Cassandra but need some help in adjusting the code.

Right now I have this which works:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['111.111.111.111'])

session = cluster.connect('testingKeyspace')

with open('dataImport.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        session.execute (
            """
            INSERT INTO tstTable (id, accts, info)
            VALUES (%s)
            """ $ (line)
        )
```

but when i run it in async like this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['111.111.111.111'])

session = cluster.connect('testingKeyspace')

with open('dataImport.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        session.execute_async (
            """
            INSERT INTO tstTable (id, accts, info)
            VALUES (%s)
            """ $ (line)
        )
```

I get this error:

```
", consistency=Not Set>' request_id=187 result=(no result yet) exception=None host=10.205.111.43>
<ResponseFuture: query='<SimpleStatement query="
```

why is async giving me that error back and not sure single executes.

fair warning...my first time using python so in learning mode here...

Answer (score 0):

got it working:

```
with open('dataImport.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        query = SimpleStatement (
            "INSERT INTO tstTable (id, accts, info) VALUES (%s) " %(line),
            consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
        session.execute_async (query)
```